# Prove that $f_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{x} \chi _{[\frac 1 n, 2]}$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,2]$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let the sequence of functions $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be defined by $f_{n}:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f_{n}(x) = \left\{ \begin{eqnarray} 
0 &,& 0 \le x < \frac 1 n \\
\frac 1 x &,& \frac 1 n \le x \le 2 \\
\end{eqnarray} \right.$.

I know that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwisely to $f(x) = \frac 1 x$. Can someone show that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,2]$?

Comment: Are you sure that the statement of this problem is correct? your sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ makes no reference to $n$...

Comment: As it is constant, it is indeed uniformly convergent.

Comment: In that case, let $\epsilon>0$. Let $N=1$. Then suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>N$...clearly $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\{f_{n}(x)\}=\frac{1}{x^{n}}$?? Only speculation

Comment: @AndresMejia, I had the intervals wrong.

Comment: Your edit makes even less sense.

Comment: how can one speak of uniform convergence on a changing interval? Where did you find this question?

Comment: @AndresMejia, My teachers lectures

Comment: are you **certain** that this question is being stated correctly?

Comment: @AndresMejia, Just one more thing. $f_{n}(x)=0$ for $0<x<1/n$

Comment: OK, you should have written this from the beginning, it's important.

Comment: but then how is that relevant to the interval, since you are only asking for the convergence on $[1/n,2]$. Further, please make edits in the question, not the comments, so that others (maybe more gifted than myself) can also help.

Comment: Don't slowly trickle in information expecting us to guess. In the future you need to copy the ENTIRE question, word for word. It's frustrating and a waste of time for you and potential answerers. Your question as written is STILL written poorly even though I understand what you're asking. I know the solution to this and I'll post it iff you write the question in full and write your attempt.

Comment: I think if the $f_n$ are being defined on $[0,2]$ then it's likely that the UC (or not, as the case may be) ought to pertain to $[0,2]$ as well

Comment: @AndresMejia, Does my question make sense now?

Comment: @Jake I think so, does my answer make sense? I also went through point-wise convergence, just to make a point about the difference. I hope that I construed your function correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you mean that:

$f_{n}:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ where 
 $f_{n}(x)$ = \begin{cases} 
      \ 0  \textrm{ if $x<\frac{1}{n}$} \\
       \ \frac{1}{x} \textrm{ if $x \geq \frac{1}{n}$} \\
   \end{cases}

To define uniform convergence: $(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N)(\forall x \in [0,2])(n \geq N \implies |f_{n}(x)-f(x)<\epsilon)$

Therefore to negate this: 
$(\exists \epsilon)(\forall N)( \exists x \in [0,2])(n \geq N \implies  |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon$.

To show this is not uniformly continuous, let $\epsilon=1$
Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Let  $x=\frac{1}{N+1}$

Then $x<1/N$ for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$ So $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=|0-N+1|=|N+1|>1=\epsilon$.

Therefore, we found an epsilon such that for each choice of $N$, there exists some $x$ such that $f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon$ and we are done.

---

To show pointwise convergence [I know you said you got this, but I want to hopefully make clear the difference]: you want

$(\forall x \in [0,2])(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(n \geq N \implies |f_{n}(x)-f(x)<\epsilon)$

The **order** of the quantifiers makes the *whole* difference.

Let $x \in [0,2]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then we want to somehow arrive at $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Well, by the archimedean property, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<x$, meaning that if $n>N$, we have that $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<x$. But then $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, trivially implying that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$.